# Maximum number of $4$-cycles

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, it.information-theory, coding-theory, bipartite-graphs

Suppose we have a balanced bipartite planar maximum degree $k$ graph.

How many such graphs on $2n$ vertices have at most $f(n)$ maximum number of $4$ cycles for a given function $f:\Bbb R^+\rightarrow\Bbb R^+\cup\{0\}$?

In general what is the distribution of such graphs with respect to $4$ cycles?

Comment: What is a balanced graph?

Comment: bipartite balanced each color has same number of vertices